# Is it possible to use the facebook sdk Inside webworkers?

Tags: web-worker, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to build a script that builds up the data needed for the application in the background.

I intend to use a web-worker but a lot of the activity use the graph API with JS SDK as it's source and it seems like that ain't working in a webworker.

Comment: There’s no real question. Please improve your posting.

Comment: How would you phrase the question?

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Facebook's JS SDK inside of Web Workers. Web Workers can use XHR just like regular JavaScript.

In fact, Web Workers were designed for tasks like this -- offloading data access and other long running requests from the main "UI thread" in favor of background processing.